# azure synapse integratio dataset wrong datetime format

Tags: pipeline, azure-synapse

when trying to preview an SAP Table in a Synapse integration Dataset i got the following error:

The "Timestamp" column contains an invalid value "10.04.2022 10:20:02". "10.04.2022 10:20:02" cannot be converted to DateTime type.
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

is this a configuration in SHIR or where can i check?